# CCActionSequence runs all actions at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I have a problem with using CCActionSequence in cocos2d v3.0 (iPhone, Objective-C).

I have created a label with some text. I want it to move up while fading out. After that, remove it from the scene. I created 3 actions: moveBy, Fade, and Remove. Looking at some tutorials on the web, I should be able to chain the actions together with a CCActionSequence. However, when I do this, all three actions run at the same time, essentially removing my label before the fade and move animations kick in.

```
CCLabelTTF *labelDP = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Double Points!" fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:16.0f];
labelDP.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
labelDP.position = ccp(0.5f,0.5f);
labelDP.color = [CCColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
[self addChild:labelDP];

CCAction *actionMove = [CCActionMoveBy actionWithDuration:ALERT_FADE_DURATION position:ccp(0.0f, 40.0f)];
CCAction *actionFade = [CCActionFadeOut actionWithDuration:ALERT_FADE_DURATION];
CCAction *actionRemove = [CCActionRemove action];

[labelDP runAction:actionFade];
[labelDP runAction:[CCActionSequence actions:actionMove, actionRemove, nil]];
```

Is there a setting that makes these animations run in sequence instead of simultaneously? Because from all the tutorials I see, they seem to be able to achieve it with similar lines of code as the above.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: ALERT_FADE_DURATION is a macro defined as 2.0f

Comment: Couldn't find any problem in your code, can you include all actions in sequence i.e. `[labelDP runAction:[CCActionSequence actions:actionMove, actionFade, actionRemove, nil]];` and see the effect

Comment: How is ALERT_FADE_DURATION declared?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore: tried that with same result

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is invoking `runAction` twice on the same node.

**EDIT**: As LearnCocos2D mentioned in the comments invoking `runAction` more then once should work as long as the actions are not interfering with each other (i.e. two move actions on the same node running in parallel) so it's either a behavioral change in version 3.x or maybe your ALERT_FADE_DURATION definition is too small (as noted in the comments as well)

Try using the `CCActionSpawn` action which can run actions in parallel on the same node :

```
CCAction *spawnAction = [CCActionSpawn actionWithArray:@[actionMove , actionFade]];
CCAction *sequenceAction = [CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[spawnAction]];

[labelDP runAction:sequenceAction];
```

This should give you the desired effect. First move and fade the label and only then remove it from its parent node

Comment: It's okay to call runAction: repeatedly. That's the common way of running actions in parallel as opposed to in sequence. Unless this behavior was changed in v3.

Comment: Yeah, the actions does not interfere with each other but his code looks legit so its either a change in v3 (which I could not find a source for approving that) or a problem with ALERT_FADE_DURATION as you already noted

Answer (score 0):

Try with  this:

```
CCAction *actionMove = [CCActionMoveBy actionWithDuration:ALERT_FADE_DURATION position:ccp(0.0f, 40.0f)];
CCAction *actionFade = [CCActionFadeOut actionWithDuration:ALERT_FADE_DURATION];
CCAction *actionRemove = [CCActionRemove action];

id seq = [CCActionSequence actions:actionMove, actionRemove, nil];

[labelDP runAction:[CCActionSpawn actions:actionFade, seq, nil]];
```